# What's a strategy for implementing GCP billing on a per-user/per-run basis?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

We are developing a way of automating the process of running Dataproc on GCP (everything from starting a cluster to submitting a job, and terminating the cluster) for genomic analyses.  Ultimately, we want to be aware of how much is being spent for each of these automated “runs” of Dataproc, especially as we open up our program to other users. Therefore, we would also like to automate (if possible) the process of attributing Dataproc costs to a certain GCP user (“run”). That way, at the end of each month, we can see how much was spent per user and specifically for what personal project. What is a good strategy for implementing this?

I have considered creating a separate GCP project for each user/client and tying them to a particular billing account, but is there perhaps a better way of managing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way is to apply labels to your resouces [1]. Billing data can be filtered and segmented by labels [2].

In your example, both user and client would be labels on Cluster and Job resources. Only Cluster resources are billed.

If you automation is really just a one-shot create-cluster/submit-job(s)/delete-cluster flow, then consider [Workflow Templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/workflows/overview) for automating this. Specifically Inline templates are tailor made for this kind of automation.

[1] https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2015/10/using-labels-to-organize-Google-Cloud-Platform-resources.html

[2] https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery